# how to avoid multiple message to be inserted for jquery groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery Validation plugin and i've started to group some of my fields together:

I've also added the fields to the rules section so that they are validated:

```
groups: {
           fullName: "myFirstName myLastName"
       },
       rules: {
           dobmm: {
               required: true
           },
           dobdd: {
               required: true
           }
           dobyy: {
               required: true
           }
       },
       messages: {
           dobmm: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth",
           dobdd: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth",
           dobyy: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth"
       }
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
   if (element.attr("id") == "dobmm" || element.attr("id") == "dobyy" || element.attr("id") == "dobyy") {
       error.insertAfter("#dobyy");

   } else {
       error.insertAfter(element);
   }

   });
```

I am getting the message thrice instead of printing once.how to get only one message when i try to submit form without filling any fields or else without entering any one of the field and submit

Comment: I don't know how we can help you figure this out of you don't show us the relevant HTML markup for this form?

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown any HTML so I cannot replicate anything within a demo for you.

However, you have a bunch of syntax errors that will break this plugin.  Please note my comments in the code below...

```
$('#yourform').validate({ // <- MISSING LINE
    groups: {
        fullName: "myFirstName myLastName"
    },
    rules: {
        dobmm: {
            required: true
        },
        dobdd: {
            required: true
        },     // <- MISSING COMMA
        dobyy: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        dobmm: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth",
        dobdd: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth",
        dobyy: "Please enter a valid Date of Birth"
    },         // <- MISSING COMMA
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.attr("id") == "dobmm" || element.attr("id") == "dobyy" || element.attr("id") == "dobyy") {
            error.insertAfter("#dobyy");
        } else {
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    }         // <- MISSING BRACE
});
```

Also, you have `myFirstName` and `myLastName` defined as your grouping.  However, since you don't have those field names also listed with/under anything in `rules`, I'm not sure how that is supposed to work.  The `groups` option is designed to group error messages together.  If you don't have any rules declared for `myFirstName` and `myLastName`, then there isn't going to be any messages at all.